# Create data array for google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google charts and I would like to create a simple bar chart with a data array. If I write out the data array manually like this, the chart is working fine:

```
 var data = [['Municipality', 'CWR', {role: 'style'}],
                  ['Kleinharras', 4.15,'color: #e5e4e2'],
                  ['Stillfried', 4.87,'color: #e5e4e2'],
                  ['Grub an der March', 4.95,'color: #e5e4e2'],
                  ['Großschweinbarth', 3.92,'color: #e5e4e2'],];  

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  var options = {
      title: 'Crop Water Requirement [mm]',
      vAxis: {title: 'Municipality',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}}
    };

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

However, if I want to create the data array automatically with a loop, its not working and the chart doesnt show:

```
 var data = [['Municipality', 'CWR', {role: 'style'}]];
         for (i = 0; i < valuesx.length; i++) {
                data[i + 1] = [valuesx[i], valuesy[i], 'color: #e5e4e2'];  
         }
```

If i print out both arrays, they **look identical**, however for some reason google charts doesnt accept the second data array. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure `valuesy[i]` is number not string.

Comment: its a number array, I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work but I dont really know why it didnt work in the first place. 
After the construction of my array with the loop (see code above) I do the following:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

As you can see, I am creating a new variable named data from my array that is also called data. And this is were the error occurs.

If I simply rename my data array, i.e. to data2, like this:

```
var data2 = [['Municipality', 'CWR', {role: 'style'}]];
             for (i = 0; i < valuesx.length; i++) {
                    data2[i + 1] = [valuesx[i], valuesy[i], 'color: #e5e4e2'];  
             }
```

and run this command:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2);
```

the chart finally shows.

Comment: this solution is useful to me in bar chart